# Value counts in pandas leads to error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program:

```
import pandas
import numpy

data = pandas.read_csv('gapminder.csv', low_memory=False)

data['employrate'] = data['employrate'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
data['urbanrate'] = data['urbanrate'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
data['internetuserate'] = data['internetuserate'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

print('counts for employrate')
filtered_employrate_data = data['employrate'][data['employrate'].notnull()]
employrate_count_factor = pandas.qcut(filtered_employrate_data, 10)
print(employrate_count_factor)
employrate_count = filtered_employrate_data.value_counts(employrate_count_factor)
print(employrate_count)
```

When I execute it I get:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Some results of qcut are NaN. So I decided to use notnull but took error again.

I am looking for the reason for this error and how to resolve it.

Here is a full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-293e5b5ef38c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/new/Assignment Week 2.py', wdir='D:/new')

  File "C:\Users\AOkunev\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\AOkunev\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/new/Assignment Week 2.py", line 21, in <module>
    employrate_count = filtered_employrate_data.value_counts(employrate_count_factor)

  File "C:\Users\AOkunev\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 430, in value_counts
    normalize=normalize, bins=bins, dropna=dropna)

  File "C:\Users\AOkunev\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 262, in value_counts
    if normalize:

  File "C:\Users\AOkunev\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 714, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: employrate_count_factor is of dataype category. That datatype is not a valid parameter to value_counts(). Does passing bins =10 to value_counts yield what you want? i.e. employrate_count = filtered_employrate_data.value_counts(bins=10)